# Create my own GoPro live stream

Tags: html, mobile, streaming, gopro

I am wondering if it's possible to stream from latests GoPro cameras throught mobile data.

I already have my own server and my own website, and I want to create a streaming page like this :

- Buy a GoPro which handle wifi connection
- Share my mobile data connection to my GoPro, and send my live video to my server
- Develop a simple mobile app to remote my stream and to send my location data to my server too.
- Add a streaming page to my website, with the video and my location + my browsed path from the beginning of my trip, for example on a map with the Google Map API. (I'll obviously do not add my home location)

I can develop on android and on my server, but I am wondering if it's possible to get the GoPro live video by this way. Have you some tips to help me ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Termux on Android with FFmpeg to re-stream the feed to your server or use Livestream app on iOS which has native GoPro support.